# Whats wrong with this Matlab function

Tags: matlab

```
function y = CramersRule(A,b)
[m,n] = size(A);
[o,p] = size(b);
if m~=2 | n~=2 | o~=2 | p~=1
error('the matrices must be 2*2 and 2*1')
A=[a b;c d]
b=[e;f] 
X = det([e b;f a])/det([a b;c d])
Y = det([a e;c f])/det([a b;c d])     
end
end
```

I just get the result: `CramersRule([1 2;3 4], [0;4])`, which was an example I used to test it.

Comment: Though it is not wrong, you will usually want to prevent output from showing at every step, so add a semicolon after some of those lines. Also use `||` rather than `|` for scalar `or` statements.

Comment: First, you should indent your code. What is it supposed to do? What result do you expect (you gave an input not a result)?

Answer (score 3):

There are several strange things here:

- First of all you have an if statement that contains an error, but even though there is an error you still do things inside the same statement, perhaps you wanted an `else` somewhere?
- Secondly you use `A=[a b;c d]` while a, c and d are not even defined.
- Thirdly you assign to `X` and `Y` which are never even used.
- Lastly you ask `y` as an output argument, whilst there is never an assignment to this. Perhaps you don't realize that matlab is case sensative?

All in all it is just a strange function now. Don't forget to check the mlint (warnings on the right hand side of your screen) as it can pick up most of these things.